# using fixtures in class python

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I have this simple program of class BankAccount doing usual deposit, withdraw and balance. now i want to use fixtures in the test so that the fixture creates object instances so that i don't have to run constructors in test functions

```
class BankAccount:

    def __init__(self, name, ID, creation_date, amount):
        self.name = name
        self.ID = ID
        self.creation_date = creation_date
        self.amount = amount

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.amount += amount
        print ("You Deposited: ", amount)
        print ("Your Balance is:", self.amount)

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        self.amount -= amount
        print ("You Withdrew", amount)
        print ("Your Balance is: ", self.amount)


    def view_balance(self):
        print ("Your Balance is: ", self.amount)
```

---

below is what i am trying to do. It gives me error that object BankAccount has no attribute a_creation. how do i get this done

```
@pytest.fixture()
def a_creation():
    return ("whatever", "y7te", "12/1/2018", 2000)


def test_a_creation(a_creation):
    bk = BankAccount.a_creation
    test1 = bk.creation_date
    assert test1 == "12/1/2018"
```

the error i am getting is
TypeError: **init**() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'ID', 'creation_date', and 'amount'

Comment: `bk = BankAccount(*a_creation)`